# Hiding Docker Exec output of a Postgres query

Tags: postgresql, powershell, docker

I'm using a Powershell script to start a Docker container with Postgres:

```
docker run -p ${host_port}:${remote_port} --name $container_name -d $database_name

# 0b. Wait for the container and the postgres database to be ready
Do
{
    echo "Waiting for database system to start up..."
    $timeout++
    sleep 1
} until ((docker exec $container_name psql --username=$database_user_name --dbname=$database_name --command="SELECT 1;") -Or ($timeout -eq $timeout_limit))

if ($timeout -eq $timeout_limit) 
{
    Throw "Database system failed to start up."
    exit
}
else {
    # Do stuff
}
```

An issue I ran into was that the database was not always ready by the time I imported my schema. I added the Do-Until loop to continue "pinging" the database until it gets a response, or until 10 seconds have passed.

This works okay. And this is the console output:

```
Waiting for database system to start up...
psql: FATAL:  the database system is starting up 
Waiting for database system to start up...
```

Is there any way to prevent that second line from appearing?

```
psql: FATAL:  the database system is starting up
```

I've tried to redirect the "pinging" to `/dev/null` but this fails when executing it like so,

```
docker exec $container_name psql --username=$database_user_name --dbname=$database_name --command="SELECT 1;" > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have to redirect Stderr too. How does `2>&1` instead of just `>` work?